# Flutter - The text inside the button does not change

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I'm creating a timer, and it has a play and pause button that changes the text inside the timer, I press "Play" and the timer starts counting, but when I pause, the text on the button and the text inside the timer doesn't change, does anyone know why?

```
AnimatedBuilder(
                  animation: controller,
                     builder: (context, child) {
                       return Padding(
                         padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 0),
                         child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
                           backgroundColor: Colors.grey[50],
                             onPressed: () {
                               if (controller.isAnimating){
                                 controller.stop();
                                 }
                               else {
                                 controller.reverse(
                                     from: controller.value == 0.0
                                         ? 1.0
                                         : controller.value);
                               }
                             },
                             icon: Icon(controller.isAnimating
                                 ? Icons.pause
                                 : Icons.play_arrow),
                             label: Text(
                                 controller.isAnimating ? "Pause" : "Play")),
                       );
                     }),
```

[Normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CIiT.png)

[Couting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06jgC.png)

[Paused](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEbSR.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try call `controller.stop();` into a `setState`

like this:

```
setState(() {
  controller.stop();
});
```